# Couldn't find Order without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a rails rookie with a weak understanding of the backend, and a difficult time learning it.  I'm trying to get product, order, cart, and line item models and controllers in sync for a "simple" ecommerce app.  Running into the following issue, which my go-to "mentor" does not have an answer for (or is tired of my questions).

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LineItemsController#create

Couldn't find Order without an ID

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
@cart = current_cart
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@order = Order.find(session[:order_id])

line_item = @order.line_items.build(line_item_attributes)
```

I'm not sure which other code is relevant enough to insert here.  Please let me know what else I can provide.

I notice that some gentlemen on here enjoy snapping at young foolish rookies like myself; if thats you, hold back.

Thank you.

Comment: can you paste the relevant routes? in the routes.rb file where you presumably have defined `resource :line_items` and all the nested stuff before and after it

Comment: It would seem the value of `session[:order_id]` is `nil`, thus you can't find an order without an id.  I would throw a `Rails.logger.info session[:order_id].to_yaml` in your controller and then look at the logs to see what it is returning.

Comment: are you using sessions or params to get ids?

Comment: I appreciate the responses from all and am investigating every angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would greatly benefit you to go through [Michael Hartl's excellent Rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book), which will make issues like this one seem trivial by the time you're through it.

But the bottom line is this:  `session[:order_id]`'s value is `nil` - it isn't being defined before your LineItems' create action is called.  Therefore, your `@order` variable isn't being populated by the line `@order = Order.find(session[:order_id])`.  But trust me, you're going to run into far more complex issues than this one building a eCommerce app, so you really should give that tutorial a shot!

Comment: Thanks- making progress in Hartl's tutorial.  But also rushing to finish this app. How would you define the order before the create action?

Comment: Off the top of my head, without seeing more of your code, I'd say this: You're currently sending `params[:product_id]` to the create action.  You should also send `params[:order_id]` (rather than trying to store that info in the session data).  So you'll need to collect & send the order_id to the page that submits to the LineItemsController#create action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `params[:order_id]` instead of `session[:order_id]`.  Isn't :order_id being passed in from a form?